# How to go back to video where it was paused in html after submitting form data?

Tags: html, database, servlets, html5-video

I have made one html page. And in that video tag is added. Now after certain time videos pauses and one form comes up, And the data of that form is submitted using servlet. Now i want go back to same state of video where it was paused. What should i use in servlet to do that. Because

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getHeader("referer"));
```

goes back to starting of the page.

**EDITED**

i am doing this `document.cookie="currentTime=video.currentTime";` on submitting of form, and this

```
vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", function()
    {   
        if(getCookie("currentTime")!==0){
            video.currentTime=getCookie("currentTime");
        }
```

in event listener, whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's not a lot you can do server-side to do that.  But in the JavaScript on the page, you can bind event handlers to the video.  Specifically, if you bind the [progress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/progress) event, you can keep track of where the user is.  You could set a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) when you get the progress event and overwrite it as the events come in, then when the user goes back to the page, [make the video seek](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) to the last time you saved.

Comment: when forwarded to the previous page, how can i overwrite timing of video?

Comment: Also localStorage would help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667925/save-html5-video-currenttime-before-user-leaves-or-closes-page and about overwrite time of video http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461669/seek-to-a-point-in-html5-video

Answer (score 0):

You can create a different servlet for capturing form response and submit the form using ajax which will prevent refresh of the page thus saving the position of seek in video tag.

Comment: can you elaborate more on this because i am new to this.?

Comment: For submitting form you must be sending response to action url in form, instead of that create a separate servlet ( for e.g formResponse ) for capturing form response. set action in form to formResponse.And onSubmit of form send request using ajax (let me know if u not aware of ajax) on success of ajax call u can hide the form and resume the video play

Comment: i am not aware of ajax

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7q19Lom8/ look at this snippet, i have created a basic form and submitting its response using ajax using jQuery, you can google ajax form submission and learn about it more.